# Why is mobile web app performance slow compared to native app?

Tags: android, ios, webkit, mobile-safari, native

It is said that if we want our mobile apps to have high performance, we should go for native apps. What is the reason for the same?
I mean why do web apps have slower performance compared to native apps?

Is it only because of loading time from server? In the case of large data, that can be true.
But what are the other cases ?

Answer (score 6):

Native apps will be compiled where as webapps will be interpreted.

On desktop class machines, JIT compilation will improve the speed of JavaScript applications but on mobile devices, the cost of the JIT in terms of CPU and power may be prohibitive. However, as power management improves, the expense of the JIT drops and on device compilation of javascript becomes an option. This has can be seen in the kitkat release of android where the [Chrome Browser and the V8 Javascript engine are used in the default WebView](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/webview/overview)